# How to add a color to a title bar PWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have my current app I am working on, the problem is I want to make the title bar of some color rather than classic white, but is not working, I saw Starbucks pwa and they have the title bar green how to add color ?, the theme color simply shows only when the app loads on windows then defaults back to white.

[image]

```js
{
  "short_name": "app",
  "name": "app",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/icon-48x48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-maskable-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icon-maskable-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/app",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#0d4c73",
  "background_color": "#00FF00",
  "description": "yada yada yada"
}
```

my index.html looks like

```js
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="bla blaba" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords" />
    <!-- <meta name="theme-color" content="#383838" /> -->
    <meta name="background-color" content="#4222e1" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
 
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.
      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->

    <!-- IOS -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="red" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="PWAGram" />

    <!-- Windows -->
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="red" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="red" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="ms-icon-144x144.png" />
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="browserconfig.xml" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <title>App</title>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this inside your HTML's `<head>`

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#0ed3cf">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#0ed3cf">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#0ed3cf">
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add a `theme_color` key to your `manifest.json`. More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps-chromium/how-to/icon-theme-color#choose-a-theme-color).

Comment: I did already but it was not working ! on chrome windows 11, this theme_color thing works only when app is loading.

Comment: Please include this information in your answer along with your `manifest.json`.